# Smoothing out current spikes so three-phase machine doesn't exceed site's electrical supply

Tags: power, mains, three-phase, high-current

We are looking at installing a machine at one of our manufacturing sites that draws around 120A at 415V three-phase (we are in the UK) but the maximum current we can draw at our site is 100A before the breakers trip. We have some other equipment at the site as well, but its all much smaller so most of that 100A should be available.

The machine operates for around 5 seconds, and then does nothing for around 3 minutes while we change over parts. Is it possible to smooth out the current spikes somehow so the site's electrical supply can handle it?

I have found some information about peak shaving and load smoothing systems but they generally seem to be large battery banks for covering peaks with time periods of hours not seconds.

We have discussed increasing the electrical supply with the power company and unfortunately it is not possible without some major upgrades in the area.

Comment: What does the machine do? Is it essentially a 3-phase motor which is using most of the power?

Comment: Would a rotary converter with a BIG flywheel work?

Comment: How long does it take for a breaker to trip at 20% overload?

Comment: @JackB It is a hydroformer, so I don't know exactly what is using most of the power but I imagine it is a combination of the various hydraulic pumps needed to close the press and reach the operating pressure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical electrical supply systems are designed based on peak load requirements. This is fundamentally because power conversion has only become popular in recent decades as power electronics came in. In your case, it would ideal if you can find a machine that consumes load in a less intermittent way e.g lower load that just runs all the time. This allows better utilisation of equipment on utility company side and yours aswell.

Additionally for the machine you are interested in, check  the total KVA rating and KW rating of the machine. If the machine consumes a lot of reactive power (low power factor, e.g a motor load,) you could locally manage reactive power supply by using capacitor banks and ensure your real load on the utility supply is less than the sanctioned load.

Now if your load has a power factor close to unity, it means you require 120A of real load and would have to design a buffer such that you consume less then 100A from utilities and still manage to run an intermittent load at 120Amps. This would mean quite an investment with a battery charger, a set of batteries and an inverter that allows delivering a higher power. The solution would likely be expensive and periodic battery replacements may actually make it completely unfeasible.

There is one more option and that would be carefully overloading your supply. But this option again requires careful study of what type of load checks are implemented by your utility supplier and regulations. Some utility companies only monitor average load while some are very specific of peak load and have digital meters that log and report over consumption.